# Hosted a .net core api on windows server 2016 docker container, on invoking docker start, status is Exited (2147516566) instead of UP

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, windows-server-2016

I want to run multiple instances of .net core API on windows server 2016 using windows docker container. I am able to create image and container successfully, but on invoking docker start the container are not running Up instead it exited with code (2147516566).

Here is my docker file content which is in published API directory

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-nanoserver-sac2016
COPY / app/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/MyAPI.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't spend long on it, but I didn't have good luck running binaries I built myself.  The docker add in for visual studio always performs the build inside a container.  I have adapted to this.  Here is an example Dockerfile I have anonymized.  Hopefully I didn't break anything:

```
# Base image for running final product
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# build asp.net application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-sac2016 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test.Docker.Windows/Test.Docker.Windows.csproj", "Test.Docker.Windows/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Test.Docker.Windows/Test.Docker.Windows.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Test.Docker.Windows"
RUN dotnet build "Test.Docker.Windows.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.Docker.Windows.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

# startup.bat contains dotnet test.Docker.Windows.dll
CMD ./startup.bat
```

Comment: I got the same error. And based on you answer I changed the target image to be SDK, too. This solved the issue although it has a drawback - the target image is much larger.